# C# string to float to int coversion

Tags: c#, string, int, type-conversion

What is the best way for converting string (decimal number) into integer in C#?
In my case, message is a string with coordinates that are separated with {x:y} 
This is not working for me (don't know why):

```
string[] coordinates = Regex.Split(message, "{x:y}");
int coord_X = (int) float.Parse(coordinates[0]);
int coord_Y = (int) float.Parse(coordinates[1]);
```

Message is equal to: -5.5707855{x:y}0.8193512{x:y}
coord_X is -55707855 (should be -5.5707855)
coord_Y is 8193512 (should be 0.8193512)

Comment: Aehm, an integer number doesn't contain any decimal

Comment: Divide them by `10.000.000` and don't cast them to `int`?

Comment: But i tried your code coord_X was -5 and coord_Y was 0.  you don't need to convert it to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int doesn't support decimals. You can either use decimal, float or double.

There are several ways to convert those Types.

Take a look at the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

The `Int` datatype cannot contain a fractional part. Try this

```
var message = "-5.5707855{x:y}0.8193512{x:y}";
string[] coordinates = Regex.Split(message, "{x:y}");
var coord_X = float.Parse(coordinates[0]); // or decimal.Parse
var coord_Y = float.Parse(coordinates[1]); // or decimal.Parse

console.WriteLine(coord_X); // -5.5707855
console.WriteLine(coord_Y); // 0.8193512
```

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing without specifying the `IFormatProvider` (e.g. CultureInfo). The *point* char in your string input might be interpreted as *thousand separator* (instead of decimal) if the locale of your machine is set this way (e.g. Italian, French, etc...).
In that case the `Parse` method would (correctly) return 55 millions etc instead of 5.5 etc...
To control all these details explicilty I suggest you use this overload of `Parse`:

```
public static float Parse(
    string s,
    NumberStyles style,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

If you need to go from `float` to `int` I prefer doing a conversion instead of a cast (for clarity):

```
int coord_X = Convert.ToInt32(float.Parse(lines[0]));
```

Being an `int`, `coord_X` will be **rounded** to the nearest integral number.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
      string s = "-5.5707855{x:y}0.8193512{x:y}";
      MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches( s, @"(.+?)\{x:y}", RegexOptions.None );
      double coord_X = double.Parse( matchCollection[ 0 ].Groups[ 1 ].Value );
      double coord_Y = double.Parse( matchCollection[ 1 ].Groups[ 1 ].Value );
```